# Split randomly dataset which is pair of images and xml annotation files and move into train and test directories

Tags: python

I have a big dataset contains images files  and xml files in  one directory. Each image has an xml file with same name(except the extension)  for example: "image01.jpg"  and its xml file "image01.xml" ...etc.
My  directory is as follows :
    |--/dataset/   " contains pair of xml and jpg images 
    |--/train "currently empty"
    |--/test  "currently empty"

I want to split this dataset **randomly** into train and test directory, for example 80% for train and 20% for test using python.
I appreciate if someone could help? 
I wrote the following code but stuck and  couldn't figure out how to move pair of files, an image-file and its xml-file (they have the same name except of the extension).

```
import glob
import random
import shutil

for i in glob.glob("./dataset/.*"):
    if i.endswith("xml"):
        i = xm_file
    else:
        i = im_file
        if xm_file[:-4] == im_file[:-4]: # pair of files 
            for file in len(os.listdir("dataset"))*0.20 :
                random.choice(shutil.move(file,"../test/"))
```

Comment: I appreciate any advice, I already spend three whole days working on it but couldn't come with a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would split the task into two parts:

In part1 I would generate a list of the image names (i.e. stripped of `.xml` or `.jpeg`) and split into test/train samples. I would make use of the `train_test_split` method from scikit-learn which is designed for this purpose and has some convenient functionality.

```
import os
from glob import glob
import shutil
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# do test train splitting

# find image names
image_files = glob("./dataset/*.jpeg")
# remove file extension
image_names = [name.replace(".jpeg","") for name in image_files]
# Use scikit learn function for convenience
test_names, train_names = train_test_split(image_names, test_size=0.2)
```

Next I would move the test and train samples to their respective directories:

```
def batch_move_files(file_list, source_path, destination_path):
    for file in file_list:
         image = file+'.jpeg'
         xml = file+'.xml'
         shutil.move(os.path.join(source_path, image), 
                     os.path.join(destination_path, image))
         shutil.move(os.path.join(source_path, xml),
                     os.pathjoin(destination_path, xml))
    return

source_dir = "./dataset/"
test_dir = "./test/"
train_dir = "./train/"
batch_move_files(test_names, source_dir, test_dir)
batch_move_files(train_names, source_dir, train_dir)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir   so much, I will test it and feedback.

Comment: Just to state it explicitly: this requires the function [`train_test_split()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) of the library/package `scikit-learn` (which by the way is a fantastic package)

Comment: I got this error message::
ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.

Comment: It sounds like the input list for train_test_split `image_names` is empty. Check `image_names` and `image_files` to figure out if it's the file selection or renaming that is going wrong.

Comment: You are right image_names were empty because we forgot to add "./dataset/*.jpeg"

Comment: But an issue with shutil and path, I think it is  a windows problem of python /  and windows \:

Comment: An issue with path:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './dataset/./dataset\\im10.jpg'

Comment: I think I need to try it in ubuntu instead of windows10

Answer (score 1):

Made a few changes as I didn't get right results for the voted answer.

```
import os
from glob import glob
import shutil
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#getting list of images
image_files = glob("E:/ML/DataSet/*.jpg")

#replacing the extension
images = [name.replace(".jpg","") for name in image_files]

#splitting the dataset
train_names, test_names = train_test_split(images, test_size=0.3)

def batch_move_files(file_list, source_path, destination_path):
    for file in file_list:
        #extracting only the name of the file and concatenating with extenions
        image = file.split('\\')[1] + '.jpg'
        xml = file.split('\\')[1] + '.xml'
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_path, image), destination_path)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_path, xml), destination_path)
    return

source_dir = "E:/ML/DataSet/"
test_dir = "E:/ML/test/"
train_dir = "E:/ML/train/"
batch_move_files(train_names, source_dir, train_dir)
batch_move_files(test_names, source_dir, test_dir)
```